# Is it possiable to retrive siginal from a sleeped windows PC to a USB device?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, usb

I want to design a USB device that can retrive siginal(like IM message) from a sleeped windows 7 PC. Is it possiable? If not, how about from a locked windows 7 PC? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sleeping PC isn't running any software at all, so it's not processing data from the network, and can't get IM data.

A locked PC is running software; it's selectively ignoring keyboard and mouse input unless that input is the right password.

Therefore, you can do this for a locked PC, but you'd have to write the kind of software that always runs. Not WinForms/WPF then, but a "service". The USB part is simple, though: just implement USB class HID (Human Input Device).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do that from a sleeped pc. And you can do it with locked PC, but you will need to write some complex software for PC that will generate signals for usb port, supplying your device with needed information. And the complexity of realizing your idea heavily depends on what exactly you want to get from PC. 
BTW Asus made something similar, usb device with lcd screen which let the user chat, play audio, view images and etc.